# Receiving Error on Xcode: "An administrator must request identities before they can be downloaded."

Tags: xcode

So I am using Xcode 5 to publish my first app on the App Store, but for some reason it is saying that I must request identities before they can be downloaded. Well, I am the administrator and I searched online for 3 hours looking for a solution. I did possibly EVERYTHING on Google, Youtube, and *even* StackOverflow. I am just hoping now that I will get a renewed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following these instructions. You need to generate a Distribution Certificate, use that certificate to create an Ad Hoc or Distribution Provisioning Profile, download and import that profile into Xcode, Archive your app, and validate it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH1-SW1

http://anthonytietjen.blogspot.com/2012/08/overcoming-trouble-validating-your.html

Also, go into Build Settings for your project and go to Code Signing. Make sure the Code Signing Identities are all set to the iDevice Distribution App ID you created in iTunes Connect as well as the Provisioning Profile set to the Provisioning Profile you painstakingly created in the iOS Development Center as well (that Ad Hoc provisioning profile file you created and downloaded into Xcode.)

I would say that if you still can't get it working with an Ad Hoc provisioning profile, try generating an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile within the "Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles" portion of the Development center , import it into Xcode (by refreshing the provisioning profile list under Xcode->preferences->accounts->details->refresh button) and go through the validation process of your archive again. I'm not sure if it's because Xcode can't validate an Archive with an Ad Hoc profile or what, but it seems to pick up the Distribution Provisioning Profile just fine and allows you to validate.  Don't worry, even if you don't validate the archive with the Ad Hoc provisioning profile, you can still create the .ipa for your archive by hitting the Distribute button in Organizer->Archives and choosing the Ad Hoc profile so that you can beta test it.

Comment: It was the App Store provisioning profile that sorted it for me. I'd forgotten that there were two types of provisioning profile and I'd been using the Ad-Hoc. Once I'd generated, downloaded and installed the App Store provisioning profile the Validate/Distribute to App Store worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Also one other reason for this which I faced was that I had renamed the project since I first started it. The CFBundleIdentifier was set to com.ABC.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}. Turns out that the ${..} was evaluating to not my current project(renamed) name when I was trying to validate gave the the same No identities… message. Changed this entry to com.ABC.my-new-project. Rebuilt the archive which now I could validate.

So watch out for project renames.